# ssl_error_rx_record_too_long when sending FROM to bank

Tags: forms, post, ssl, bank

i am trying to send a  to the bank with the details of the payment.
The bank tells me that i have to make a POST  with action to their URL with ssl:

... (all hidden values)

what im trying to do is send all the info with a header(location: 'https://www.bankurl.com?var1=111&var2=222&var3=333&... ')
those this work the same as a POST FORM?

All i get is this error ssl_error_rx_record_too_long, how can i fix this? is it problem of my server? or the banks server?

On my server i havent got SSL, but the bank has told me i dont need it.

Any body knows the answer?
thank allot!

Answer (score 0):

i did it with the form and an auto submit with java.
all worked well.

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? If so, elaborate on your answer and accept it as answer to your question.